# Ruby - Extract data from string with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

In ruby I have string that looks like this:

```
"\/v1\/195900\/patients?DEPARTMENTID=162&GUARANTORCOUNTRYCODE3166=1&offset=20"
```

how can I extract offset value from this string with regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't satisfy your requirement to use a regex, but here is a way:

```
uri = "\/v1\/195900\/patients?DEPARTMENTID=162&GUARANTORCOUNTRYCODE3166=1&offset=20"

require "uri"
URI.decode_www_form(URI(uri).query).assoc("offset").last
# => "20"
```

or

```
URI.decode_www_form(URI(uri).query).to_h["offset"]
# => "20"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming offset will always be present as `offset=` and it will always be a numeric value

```
str = "\/v1\/195900\/patients?DEPARTMENTID=162&GUARANTORCOUNTRYCODE3166=1&offset=20"
str.scan(/offset=(\d+)/)
#=> [["20"]]
```

Comment: You can use a *positive lookbehind* to avoid the nested array: `str.scan(/(?<=offset=)\d+/)`, or - since there is probably only one "offset" - just `str[/(?<=offset=)\d+/]`